# How to calculate the energy required to generate a vortex?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

I am looking for the formula to calculate how much energy it requires to create a vortex. Can anyone assist please?

Comment: More details? What type of vortex are you talking about? Do you mean a quantized vortex in superfluid?

Answer (score 2):

There is as far as I know no simple formula for the energy of a vortex. I am not a fluid dynamicist, but here are some problems you encounter in the theoretical computation. Hopefully a fluid dynamicist can clarify a workable practical formula: I am almost certain that such a formula will come from experiment as I hope to show by outlining the problems in defining an energy expression.

Firstly, there are many different kinds of vortex, as you can see from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex). Practically, most vortices are wont to swiftly take on an *irrotational* flow pattern - this does **not** imply lack of "whirlpools" - this simply means that elements of fluid have zero spin angular momentum whilst a given mass element of fluid as a constant orbital angular momentum about the vortex line. In symbols, the complex potential for a 2D vortex is ([See the Wikipedia page for "Potential Flow"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow) ):

$$\Omega(z) = \frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi\,i}\,\log z$$

where $z = x+i\,y$ is the 2D position in the flow and $\Gamma$ the *circulation*. The implied velocity field is:

$$V(z) = (\mathrm{d}_z \Omega)* = -\frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi\,i\,z^*} = \frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi\,r} i\,e^{i\,\theta}$$

where we now write the position vector in polar co-ordinates $(r,\theta)$ *i.e.* the velocity is at right angles to the position vector, and the streamlines are concentric circles centred at the origin. The spin angular momentum of the fluid per unit volume is $\rho\,\nabla\wedge \vec{v} = 0$, aside from at the logarithmic branch point at the origin, and the orbital angular momentum per unit volume is $\frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi}$, *i.e.* constant. Note that this flow is precisely analogous to the magnetic field lines around a DC current thread. We see that the circulation around any loop $\Lambda$ not containing the origin is $\int_\Lambda \vec{v}\cdot\,\mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \int_\Lambda \mathrm{d}_z\Omega\,\mathrm{d}z = 0$, whereas for any loop $\tilde{\Lambda}$ containing the origin:

$$\int_\tilde{\Lambda} \vec{v}\cdot\,\mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \int_\tilde{\Lambda} \mathrm{d}_z\Omega\,\mathrm{d}z = \frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi\,i} \int_\tilde{\Lambda} \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{z} = \Gamma$$

Now at last to your energy formulas. The kinetic energy of the fluid inside the cylinder defined by the ring shaped region $\{(r,\,\theta):\;a < r < b\}$ per unit length of vortex line (*i.e.* per unit length normal to the 2D flow) is given by (given the flow's axisymetry about the origin):

$$\int_a^b\,2\,\pi\,r\,\rho \frac{|\vec{v}|^2}{2}\,\mathrm{d}r = \frac{\Gamma^2}{4\,\pi}\log\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

which diverges as either $a\to0$ or $b\to\infty$. So you see that in simple models, vortexes have infinite enengies. This is quite OK: it simply means that there is something we haven't modelled properly. The same happens for a simple model of the magnetic field around a thread when one tries to calculate the magnetic field energy, or, equivalently, the inductance of the thread conductor. The divergence for $a\to0$ means that the model simply breaks down near the vortex: all these ideas assume a continuum whereas the real fluid is made of "grains", *i.e.* molecules. Likewise, there are no thread conductors; the magnetic field is not divergent when one takes into account that the current is spread over a nonzero area. Another lack of this theory is the lack of viscosity in the fluid. When we take this into account, we get the [Lamb-Oseen Vortex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb-Oseen_vortex), which is another exact solution of the Navier-Stokes equations. Here the flow lines are the same, *i.e.* concentric circles around the origin, but the flow speed is modified by the fluid's nonzero viscosity $\eta$:

$$v(r) = \frac{\Gamma}{2\,\pi\,r}\left(1-\exp(\left(\frac{r^2}{4\,\eta\,t}\right)\right)$$

where $t$ is the time, *i.e.* the divergence has been removed ($v\to0$ as $r\to0$) and the vortex decays as $4\,\eta\,t$ increases and damps out a bigger and bigger disk shapen regoin.

However, this does not address the divergence as $b\to\infty$; the Lamb-Oseen model still has this divergence. In practice, perfect, irrotational vortexes take infinite time to set up, and their setup will involve acoustic waves propagating at finite speed. The same applies to the magnetic field: for small $r$ the irrotational vortex model applies, but at large distances, one must account for the fact that the magnetic field is established by electromagnetic waves propagating at finite speed $c$. When this fact is taken into account, the energy needed to set the vortex up will be seen to be finite. So, in closing, a practical formula for the energy contained per unit length vortex line in a vortex will be something like:

$$E = \kappa \Gamma^2$$

where $\kappa$ is probably best experimentally determined.